# making setup project for app that works in local network

Tags: c#, networking, client-server, sql-server-express, setup-deployment

I wrote a WinForms app and it runs on the local network.  My database is SQL Express, with multiple clients connecting to a central server.

I want to create setup project for my app.  How do I create a setup project that:

1. When installed on the server, it creates my database?
2. When installed on the client, it only installs my application without the database?

How do I create such a setup project, I am using VS2010 with the built-in setup and deployment features?

thanks.

Comment: English ........... `how can i make this project that when i install on server system my database's project become create and if i install setup file on client system only my app become install without database`

Answer (score 1):

What about creating two setup projects; one for the server and one for the clients?

Answer (score 0):

I personally think, that there is not much you can do with the setup project in visual stidio.you may have to switch to third party to play with setups